# How to fill in a matrix recursively in c++?

Tags: c++, matrix

So I have to fill in a square matrix recursively. For size N=5, it should be:

```
  1 1 1 1 1
  1 2 2 2 1
  1 2 3 2 1
  1 2 2 2 1
  1 1 1 1 1
```

but my program shows:

```
  1 1 1 1 1
  1 2 2 2 1
  1 2 3 3 1
  1 2 2 2 1 
  1 1 1 1 1 

void llenar5 (int** mat, int n, int f=0, int c=0,int k=2)
{
if (f<n)
{
    if (c<n)
    {
        if (f==0 ||c==0||f==n-1||c==n-1)
        {
            *(*(mat+f)+c)=1; 
            llenar5(mat,n,f,c+1,k); //move to the right
        }
        else if (f==k-1 ||c==k-1||f==n-k||c==n-k)
        {
            *(*(mat+f)+c)=k;
            llenar5(mat,n,f,c+1,k++);
        }
    }
    llenar5(mat,n,f+1,c,k);
}
```

}

I am creating a matrix in dynamic memory, and I tried calling the function llenar5(mat,n,f+1,c+1,k+1) to jump a column and row while incrementing the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
void llenar5 (int** mat, int n, int f=0, int c=0,int k=1)
{
if (f<n)
{
    if (c<n)
    {
        if (f==k-1 ||c==k-1||f==n-k||c==n-k) 
        {
            *(*(mat+f)+c)=k;
            llenar5(mat,n,f,c+1,k+1);
        }
        llenar5(mat,n,f,c+1,k);
    }
    llenar5(mat,n,f+1,c,k);
}
```

}

Comment: took me two days for the 2nd recursive call -_-

Answer (score -1):

I think it will help if you, temporarily, consider a matrix with 0-based numbers. For example, your initial matrix would look instead something like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 1 2 1 0
0 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
```

If you inspect this matrix, you should quickly observe a fundamental property of this matrix. The value of each cell is the minimum distance from the cell to its closest horizontal or vertical edge.

So, for cell at coordinates (x,y), with the matrix of size w (width) and h (height), the value of each cell is:

```
min(x, y, (w-1-x), (h-1-y))
```

Where the min() function is a classical minimum function, that computes the minimum value of its arguments.

Then, it should be obvious that going from a 0-based matrix to a 1-based matrix you should simply add 1 to the result.

So, in conclusion your code should be trivially simple:

1. Loop over all the x and y coordinates.
2. Set the value of the corresponding cell based on the above formula.

Your code seems to be unnecessarily complicated. All that recursion is completely unneeded. This can be done using a single pass over their entire matrix, top to bottom, left to right. You don't need to know the values of adjacent cells, to compute the value in the next cell.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to say, but my professor wants us to call our procedure recursively, not use another function within it recursively.